# Skyrim Brother Verulus is missing (A Taste Of Death - Quest)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have returned to Skyrim to finish the DLCs, but I noticed I have an uncompleted Miscellaneous Quest, "Speak to Verulus about the Hall of the Dead".

But I have searched all over Markarth at various hours and I can't find him, so I can't move on with the quest.

How do I check the quest status? To see if I've already completed the objectives and there is a bug that is preventing me from finishing it?

Is there a way to reset the quest?

Comment: Did you check Understone Keep too?

Comment: I have this problem too - I've finished the quests related to Brother Verulus (DA11, DA11Intro), but this objective stays firmly stuck in the journal.  If I find a solution I'll post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the initial dialogue between him and Thongor Silver-Blood, Brother Verulus can be found in the *Hall of the Dead* or inside *Understone Keep*.

UESP [lists his schedule](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Brother_Verulus) as follows:

> He starts his day in the Understone Keep at 8am, and will wander around the Keep for the entire day, eating at noon and at 6pm, before going to sleep at midnight.

He's [essential](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Essential_NPCs) until you've progressed much longer through the quest *The Taste of Death*, so he shouldn't be dead.

If you're on PC, you can use `help "Brother Verulus"` to find his [RefID](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs) and then use the command `player.moveto [RefID]` (after saving, of course) to teleport to him. The RefID will look something like `0001BB8F`, so then you'd type `player.moveto 0001BB8F`.

The [quest page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Taste_of_Death) lists another solution as well:

> Alternately, you can completely ignore Verulus and pick the lock to the hall. Entering the hall this way will trigger the main quest; however, unless you persuade or bribe him, you will not be able to befriend him using the favor quest.

However, depending on your choices later in the quest, you'll have to locate him eventually. If he's dead for some strange reason (you never know with these sandboxy games), you can try the following method posted on reddit to restore him: [[PC only] Foolproof guide to resurrecting NPCs](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/1kjlsk/pc_only_foolproof_guide_to_resurrecting_npcs/).

Comment: I have now found Brother Verulus, thanks! But I click on "What's the Hall of the Dead" in the dialogue and he speaks, but nothing changes. What can I do? I have verified the quest stage and its set to 200, but I never completed this quest.

Comment: He's supposed to ask you to investigate the Hall of the Dead, in which you will meet another person that starts the second part of the quest. Have you done that quest line already?

Comment: Ok, I have found I already completed the quest and that its a bug that it doesnt disappear from the jornal. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found him I had the same damn problem but I was making a rookie mistake I was entering the hall of the dead FROM OUTSIDE. what I didn't know is that theres more than one entrance to the hall of the dead. GO INSIDE The understone Keep and look for the entrance to the hall of the dead inside. but do not go there until 9.30am he gets to the door between 9.30am and 10am he will be guarding the entrance at this time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment on the OP's question, I also had the same problem on Skyrim Special Edition, but in my case I was certain I had finished both the DA11Intro and DA11 quests.  I also had the most up-to-date Unofficial Patch mod installed and that didn't fix it either.

This bug was hard to hack around.  Using `setstage`, `setobjectivecompleted`, and `setobjectivedisplayed` console commands do nothing to make the state of the DA11Intro quest change.  This can be confirmed with `player.sqs`.  The only solution I found was to use `resetquest DA11Intro` (which *does* actually alter the state of the quest as it should), then create and reload a new save file.  This makes the DA11Intro quest objective disappear, which really shouldn't matter if you've already completed the main DA11 quest.

I've also confirmed that there do not seem to be any negative side effects if you enter the Hall of the Dead in Markarth, or talk to Kleppr in the Sliver-blood Inn.  It's as if the quest is simply gone, which is exactly what I want.  Just in case it's relevant (and to avoid too many spoilers) I sided with the Daedra when I completed DA11.  It's possible the outcome of this hack might be different had I resolved the quest differently but I didn't test that hypothesis.

It's times like these that I wish I could see the papyrus script for this quest - might give some insight on why it's such a bitch to fix =)